# How is LoadBalancerClientFactory.PROPERTY_NAME set?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I'm trying to develop a custom DiscoveryClient but when it uses `lb://` it doesn't work correctly.  I have instatiated a `DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier` using `@Import(LoadBalancerClientConfiguration.class)` in the application class.

Looking through the code there is notion of

```
this.serviceId = environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);
```

but whenver I debug it, I get `null` for that value.

Comment: Why did you instantiate one of those on your own? Can you show your bean declarations?

Comment: It took a while but I can't seem to find the documentation around this...
adding
@LoadBalancerClients(defaultConfiguration = LoadBalancerClientConfiguration.class)

got the DiscoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier instantiated and worked correctly as a load balancer.

Comment: Going to delete this post rather than repurposing it.  The real question would be how do I enable `DiscoveryClient` that provides URLs to work with Spring-Cloud Load Balancer  In the end it's that lat comment I had but couldn't find anywhere in the documentation where it was.